# Variable initialisation conflict with counter

Tags: c++

The objective for the following code is to do a procedure once every 16 transmissions:
cw in the code is the value of contention window (its technical knowledge is not important here)

```
int Nt;
Nt = (Nt + 1) % 16;
if (Nt == 0) 
cw_ = cw * 16;  // action once transmission count is 16
 else
    cw_ = cw;
```

The problem is I have to initialize the value for Nt, otherwise the code may become prone to future errors; but I cannot put **int Nt = 0** in the code as it will get executed every time and I need the value of Nt to increment after each time the above code is run to obtain the count of 16.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"The problem is I have to initialize the value for Nt, otherwise the code may become prone to future errors; "* - Too late; it is already an error.  It is undefined behavior to read an uninitialized variable and it's initial value is indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

Store `Nt` permanently somewhere else. Alternatively, but this has drawbacks like global variables, make it static within the function.